# VBA - where are "available references" stored?

Tags: excel, vba, reference, com, typelib

In Excel (or other MS Office apps), when you go to the VBA IDE, the Tools, References list shows you currently selected assemblies as well as a list of others you can add by checkmarking them. You can also hit **Browse** to navigate to a folder containing a .TLB file of your own making.

But there's a problem. Let's say you you browse to **C:\Fubar\PumpHandle.tlb** and add it. Everything works fine. A week later, you uncheckmark the reference, because you don't need it in the VBA project your are working on. No problem: PumpHandle is still on the Available References list -- it's just not checkmarked.

A week after that, you delete **C:\Fubar\PumpHandle.tlb**. Now go into the VBA IDE, Tools, References, and PumpHandle is still on the list, with **no way to remove it**. Waaaaaah! If you checkmark it, you will of course get an error message, because the PumpHandle.tlb file does not exist. How can you remove it from the Available References list? I have tried searching the Registry and deleting all references to PumpHandle.tlb, but it still shows up in the Available References list. I have tried searching everywhere in %APPDATA%, but I can not find PumpHandle anywhere in there either. Finally, I have looked inside the .xls? --> .zip file of Personal.xlsb, and can't find it in there.

So -- where does the machine store that (obsolete and unusable but highly confusing) reference? How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where they are stored.  Maybe this will get you where you want to go, however.

```
' You need to add a reference to Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibilty
Sub ZapReference()
Dim VBAEditor As VBE, VBProj As VBProject, VBRef As Reference

    Set VBAEditor = Application.VBE
    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    
    For Each VBRef In VBProj.References
        If VBRef.IsBroken Then
            Debug.Print "Removing: ", VBRef.Name, VBRef.FullPath
            VBProj.References.Remove VBRef
        End If
    Next VBRef
End Sub
```

Comment: To run this, you may need to update your Trust Center options.  See [What does 'Error 1004: Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project is not trusted' mean?](https://support.pcmiler.com/en/support/solutions/articles/19000047036-what-does-error-1004-programmatic-access-to-visual-basic-project-is-not-trusted-mean-)

Answer (score 0):

This list is loaded from the registry. The information is put into the registry when you run a command line `regsvr32.exe` (plain ol' COM) or `regasm.exe` (.NET COM). This usually happens at installation time and is cleaned up at uninstallation time. Deleting the file won't remove it from the list.

There are a few locations where it could exist in the registry, depending on whether it's a 32-bit or 64-bit type library and upon whether it's registered for all users or only the current user. The list below is (roughly) in order of most common to least common.

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Classes\TypeLib
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\TypeLib

Comment: I can find **valid** references in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Classes\TypeLib, but I cannot find bogus ones anywhere in the registry. By "bogus" I mean a reference that was added a while ago but whose actual .dll (and .tlb) files were subsequently deleted. The reference is still in the Available References list, but it is not in the registry. My COM component is written in C# and made Com-Visible. It works just fine when the .dll and .tlb are where I first had them. But if I move them, the .DLL cannot be loaded. The ghost Available References entry stays there, taunting me.

Comment: Did you check the other locations? Try searching the registry for your filename.

Comment: I believe what when a COM-visible component is registered, the registration process only puts a reference to the .DLL in the registry. It does not add PumpHandle.tlb in the registry anywhere. The .tlb is used by Excel when you add a reference in the VBA IDE. At that point, Excel reads the .tlb file and remembers the interfaces it finds there so that early binding intelli-sense will work. But I cannot for the life of me figure out where Excel stores that information. I can delete every key related to PumpHandle (paths, dll''s, etc.), yet Excel still shows PumpHandle in the Available References.

Comment: Yes, I checked everywhere. I did RegEdit search just for PumpHandle, which finds anything and everything with that string in it. Not there.

Comment: It's possible that Excel caches some information in VBA project binary that's stored in the spreadsheet. If you want to look there, you'll need to find a tool that can read it.

Comment: I searched the registry for PumpHandle, then deleted absolutely everything found by the search. I then rebooted. Removed Personal.xlsb from XLSTART. Searched my machine for any other .xlsb. Deleted the Excel15.xlb file from AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel (because I noticed that its modified date is today). Launched Excel. Alt-F11, then Tools, References. The ghost of Pumphandle was still there. I am now doing a Quick Repair of Office, and if that doesn't work I'll do a full repair, then report back.

Comment: Quick repair of Office 365 didn't help. Did a complete repair, rebooted, launched Excel, blank workbook, Alt+F11, Tools, References -- Pumphandle is gone. I conclude that Office is storing the Available References somewhere in a program file, presumably in the C:\Program Files (x86) folder structure. I searched Event Viewer for PumpHandle - not found in any event list. Next tactic: I will leave the machine untouched until tomorrow, then add a reference to PumpHandle (in its current location). I'll then search all files in c:\program files (x86) for any modified that day.

Comment: I may not be all that bright, but I'm damned persistent.

Comment: The ghost reference items must get written to a binary file. I wrote a PowerShell script that examines every file with a modified date after x. I set x to right now, then went into Excel VBA, added a reference, saved, and exited. I ran the PowerShell script, which looked at the contents of each newly modified file (including System and Hidden files) searching for PumpHandle. It scored some hits -- but they were in binary files that I couldn't easily read (don't have a hex viewer app on that machine). So I just gave up. Maybe sometime I'll spin up a VM and try the process again..